# Is there a generic "isolate a single byte" bit mask for all systems, irrespective of CHAR_BIT?

Tags: c, byte

If `CHAR_BIT == 8` on your target system (most cases), it's very easy to mask out a single byte:

```
unsigned char lsb = foo & 0xFF;
```

However, there are a few systems and C implementations out there where `CHAR_BIT` is neither 8 nor a multiple thereof. Since the C standard only mandates a *minimum* range for `char` values, there is no guarantee that masking with `0xFF` will isolate an entire byte for you.

I've searched around trying to find information about a generic "byte mask", but so far haven't found anything.

There is always the O(n) solution:

```
unsigned char mask = 1;
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
{
    mask |= (mask << i);
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is any O(1) macro or line of code somewhere that can accomplish this, given how important this task is in many system-level programming scenarios.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can you name a system where `CHAR_BIT` is different from 8?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "byte"? Do you want to mask out `CHAR_BIT` bits? Then just shift `1` left by `CHAR_BIT` and subtract `1` to get the bit mask.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sure: The PDP-8, which has 12-bit bytes

Comment: @Jabberwocky: it is not about a "system" but about compiler. Compiler will choose the size of char, int, long. It can decide to emulate them. In any case, we can assume safely that all true compiler have CHAR_BIT = 8, or we could not read files, exchange data on internet, etc. In C there is this, trigraphs and few other "obsolete/not in real world" stuffs. Quality of compiler mandates char being 8 bit.

Comment: As it turns out, for high portability, the possible types of `foo` needs consideration - especially its sign-ness.  What is your interests?

Comment: @chux Normally when I am working with raw bits I use unsigned types, though this question was intended to be as generic as possible

Comment: @GovindParmar "generic as possible" means defined behavior when  `CHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX`, various endian, integer encodings, padding, constants, C89 or later, `foo` is `double` (including values outside the integer range, NaN, infinity), a pointer, complex numbers, in addition to `CHAR_BIT > 8`.  At least we could require `foo` is an integer type and IMO, at least C99.

Comment: @chux Sure. Okay, `foo` is an integral type and we're on C99.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to extract an `unsigned char` from an integer value is simply to cast it to `unsigned char`:

```
(unsigned char) SomeInteger
```

Per C 2018 6.3.1.3 2, the result is the remainder of `SomeInteger` modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`. (This is a non-negative remainder; it is always adjusted to be greater than or equal to zero and less than `UCHAR_MAX+1`.)

Assigning to an `unsigned char` has the same effect, as assignment performs a conversion (and initializing works too):

```
unsigned char x;
…
x = SomeInteger;
```

If you want an explicit bit mask, `UCHAR_MAX` is such a mask. This is so because unsigned integers are pure binary in C, and the maximum value of an unsigned integer has all value bits set. (Unsigned integers in general may also have padding bit, but `unsigned char` may not.)

One difference can occur in very old or esoteric systems: If a signed integer is represented with sign-and-magnitude or one’s complement instead of today’s ubiquitous two’s complement, then the results of extracting an `unsigned char` from a negative value will differ depending on whether you use the conversion method or the bit-mask method.

Comment: It is actualy wrong answer as extracting the smallest addressable part of the number will not work using UCHAR_MAX as it does not have to be equal to `(1U << CHAR_BIT) - 1U` and many implementations (like TI DSP processors define UCHAR_MAX as 255 and the CHAR_BIT > 8

Comment: @P__J__ " UCHAR_MAX as 255 and the CHAR_BIT > 8" seems odd as C requires `unsigned char` to not have any padding - so those 2 conditions do not appear C complaint.

Comment: @chux No, C only requres UCHAR_MAX to be at least 2^8-1 or magnitude higher and it is left to the implementation. It does not break that rule as if the CHAR_BIT > 8 no padding (ie no another addressable unit has to added to pad it). So sizeof will always return the correct result. The padding is not used in standard in the mening of bit-padding only byte padding. Here only part of the char is not used. So in those implementations  any value > UCHAR_MAX is a trap representation

Comment: @P__J__: The C standard does not “only” require `UCHAR_MAX` to be at least 255. In 5.2.4.2.1 1, it requires `UCHAR_MAX` to be the maximum value for an object of type `unsigned char`. Since `unsigned char` is pure binary with all value bits and no padding bits, the maximum value has all bits set, so `UCHAR_MAX` must have all bits set.

Comment: @EricPostpischil see my answer - actually the image. Standard defines only the **minimum** value and actual one is left to the implementation.

Comment: @P__J__: No, the standard does not define **only** the minimum value. The minimum value is **one** of the requirements that the standard requires that `UCHAR_MAX` satisfy. Per the text “Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater…,” the standard requires that `UCHAR_MAX` be at least 255. Per the text “maximum value for an object of type `unsigned char`,” the standard requires that `UCHAR_MAX` be the maximum value for an `unsigned char`. An implementation must satisfy **both** of those requirements. If `CHAR_BIT` exceeds 8, `UCHAR_MAX` must exceed 255; it must match.

Comment: It is your over interpretation of the  Standard. Nothing else.

Comment: When `UCHAR_MAX` is of type `int`, and then with non-2's complement systems, the `& UCHAR_MAX` mask has an advantage over the `(unsigned char)` cast as `SomeInteger` is not converted to a different sign-ness and then avoid messing its bit pattern.

Answer (score 3):

On review (after accept) , [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351242/2410359) answer's part about `UCHAR_MAX` makes for a preferable mask.

```
#define BYTE_MASK UCHAR_MAX
```

> The value `UCHAR_MAX` shall equal 2<sup>CHAR_BIT</sup> − 1.  C11dr §5.2.4.2.1 2

As `unsigned char` cannot have padding. So `UCHAR_MAX` is always the all bits set pattern in a character type and hence in a C "byte".

---

`some_signed & some_unsigned` is a problem on non-2's complement as the `some_signed` is convert to `unsigned` before the `&` thus changing the bit pattern on negative vales.  To avoid, the all ones mask needs to be signed when masking signed types.  The is usually the case with `foo & UINT_MAX`

---

**Conclusion**

Assume: `foo` is of some integer type.

If only 2's complement is of concern, use a cast -  it does not change the bit pattern.

```
unsigned char lsb = (unsigned char) foo;
```

Otherwise with any integer encoding and `CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX`

```
unsigned char lsb = foo & UCHAR_MAX;
```

Otherwise TBD

---

<strike>Shifting an `unsigned` 1 by `CHAR_BIT` and then subtracting 1 will work even on esoteric non-2's complement systems. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350996/is-there-a-generic-isolate-a-single-byte-bit-mask-for-all-systems-irrespectiv#comment95517530_54350996).  Be sure to use *unsigned math*.</strike>

On such systems, this preserves the bit patten unlike `(unsigned char)` cast on negative integers.

```
unsigned char mask = (1u << CHAR_BIT) - 1u;
unsigned char lsb = foo & mask;
```

Or make a `define`

```
#define BYTE_MASK ((1u << CHAR_BIT) - 1u)
unsigned char lsb = foo & BYTE_MASK;
```

---

To also handle those pesky cases where `UINT_MAX == UCHAR_MAX` where `1u << CHAR_BIT` would be UB, shift in 2 steps.

```
#define BYTE_MASK (((1u << (CHAR_BIT - 1)) << 1u) - 1u)
```

Answer (score -3):

`UCHAR_MAX` does not have to be equal to `(1U << CHAR_BIT) - 1U`

you need actually to and with that calculated value not with the UCHAR_MAX

`value & ((1U << CHAR_BIT) - 1U)`.

Many real implementations (for example TI) define UCHAR_MAX as 255 and emit the code which behaves like the one on the machines having 8 bits bytes. It is done to preserve compatibility with the code written for other targets.

For example

```
unsigned char x;

x++;
```

will generate the code which checks in the value of x is larger than UCHAR_MAX and if it the truth zeroing the 'x'

[image]

Comment: "UCHAR_MAX does not have to be equal to (1U << CHAR_BIT) - 1U" does not match the C spec which has "The value `UCHAR_MAX` shall equal `2^CHAR_BIT − 1.`"  §5.2.4.2.1 2

Comment: @chux OK so TI implemention is not conformant. But in real life if you have to program such a devices (interesting how many of SO users had any contact with CHAR_BIT > 8 devices) you need to take it into consideration. Otherwise your software will not work and the vendor supplied libraries will be useless

Comment: What Texas Instruments C implementation defines `UCHAR_MAX` as 255 and `UCHAR_MAX` as greater than eight?

Comment: I fully agree there are many non-conformant compilers one is obliged to use.  Yet to write portable code per the spec and those is a challenge.  In such cases    I'd use `#if standard do_portable_way #elif TI do_special_way`.  BTW, `1U << CHAR_BIT` is a UB when `UINT_MAX == UCHAR_MAX`.  Easy enough to fix with 2 shifts.

Comment: @chux usually if you program hardware which has bytes > 8 bits the portability is not the issue :).